# Carcassonne Bazaars and other expansions after the bid

Tags: carcassonne, expansions

When you play a Bazaar and bid though the pieces do the pieces still cause their stuff?

To be more specific, lets start with Wheel of fortune, if one of the Bazaar pieces has a Fortune mark to move the pig, does that happen when the piece came from a winning bazaar bid?  I know extra Bazaars do not cause another.

and the Builder, I put my won piece on a feature with the builder, I get another turn right?  and when does that happen, immediately?

I guess this question is looking more like "Once the bidding is done for a Bazaar does play act like each placement is a normal turn (except for any won bazaars)?  And if so what happens if on a 'second' turn another Bazaar shows up before all the others are played?  Still ignore it until all original bazaar wins have been played and play goes back to normal?

Answer (score 1):

In the rules for **Bridges, Castles and Bazaars** you can find the following text:

> Once all tiles have been claimed, the players will each place their tile (and a follower, if they
>   wish) in clockwise order from the player to the left of the active player. No follower may be
>   placed on the bazaar itself.

Later on it's said that there can be no chain reactions, that there can be only one bazaar round in one turn.

However, in the Dutch rules it says (translated):

> After all land tiles have been claimed, all players execute a normal turn where, instead of drawing a land tile, they place the recently acquired land tile in clockwise order from the player to the left of the active player.

This means something else entirely. By the English rules I would assume everything happens within the same turn. By the Dutch rules, suddenly you have many different turns triggered by the Bazaar.

I checked the German rules as well, they seem to be in line with the English rules. So I'm going with those.

The rules say you can place the tile you acquired, and a follower if you wish. Followers do not include builders, pigs and the like, so strictly I don't think you should be allowed to place those. Also, building onto a road or city that has the builder on it only gives you another turn if you are the active player:

> In a yet later turn, he places a tile that extends or completes the road with his builder on it.
>   After **completing his turn** (placing a follower and scoring), he draws and places a 2nd tile as
>   normal, including a follower if he wants.

I'm not sure about the Wheel of Fortune, haven't played it.

Answer (score 0):

It's like a nolanism and we had the same problem, or house rule is that the rule only applies only the first time and do not make a chain reaction.